# Trying to write a password generator app and I faced this problem but my program runs anyway Any idea how can I fix this?

Tags: python, python-3.x

> Operator "+=" not supported for types "Unknown | Literal['']" and "str | None"
> Operator "+" not supported for types "Literal['']" and "None"
> PylancereportGeneralTypeIssues

here is my code

```
settings = {
    'lower': True,
    'upper': True,
    'symbol': True,
    'number': True,
    'length': 8
}

def generate_random_char(choices):
    choice = random.choice(choices)
    
    if choice == 'upper':
        return get_random_uppercase()
    
    if choice == 'lower':
        return get_random_lowercase()
    
    if choice == 'symbol':
        return get_random_symbol()
    
    if choice == 'number':
        return get_random_number()
     

def password_generator(settings):
    final_password = ''
    password_length = settings['length']

    choices = list(filter(lambda x: settings[x], ['upper', 'lower', 'symbol', 'number']))
    # print(choices)

    # choices = []
    # for key, value in settings.items():
    #     if value == True: # and key != 'length':
    #         choices.append(key)
    # print(choices)

    for i in range(password_length):
        final_password += generate_random_char(choices)

    return final_password


get_settings_from_user(settings)
print(password_generator(settings))
```

Comment: Type warnings don't prevent the program from running.

Comment: These messages are just your IDE trying to be helpful; it has nothing to do with Python per se.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve the error, and may also be better practice. Right now you are essentially creating a new variable each time a new character is generated - `final_password += generate_random_char(choices)` is basically making a new variable called `final_password`, which is the `final_password` variable, with the result of `generate_random_char(choices)` at the end.

Instead, every time you generate a new character you can add it to a list, and use the `join()` function to combine all the characters in the list when you're done. Like so:

```
def password_generator(settings):
    #create an empty list called password_characters
    password_characters = []
    password_length = settings['length']

    choices = list(filter(lambda x: settings[x], ['upper', 'lower', 'symbol', 'number']))
    # print(choices)

    # choices = []
    # for key, value in settings.items():
    #     if value == True: # and key != 'length':
    #         choices.append(key)
    # print(choices)

    for i in range(password_length):
        #add new character to the list of password characters
        password_characters.append(generate_random_char(choices))

    #take all the charachters and combine them into a string, with '' (nothing) as the divider between the charachters
    final_password = ''.join(password_characters)
    return final_password
```

Comment: @KennyOstrom Oh. You think replacing 'return get_random_uppercase()' with 'return str(get_random_uppercase())' would fix it? I don't have Pylance either, and also a bunch of the code isn't included so I can't test it.

Comment: No, it's saying generate_random_char can fall through and return None. That can't happen with a normal config, and it can't happen with no entries, but the tools don't know the programmer's assumptions, they just know it's possible, and that None return that causes an error with str +, str += and str.join so it's a danger that the tools warn about.

Answer (score 0):

Those warnings come from tools that look at your code and try to spot common mistakes. I don't have pylance, but I'm pretty sure it's looking at generate_random_char() and seeing that it can return something, or it can get to the end and return None. This can probably only happen if the configuration is not valid, but it CAN happen.

Trying to add None to a string is going to fail, so it correctly flags a warning. You can fix generate_random_char by raising a configuration exception at the end, in case it didn't receive a valid choice.

```
import random
from string import ascii_lowercase, ascii_uppercase, digits, punctuation

class ConfigurationError(ValueError):
    pass

def generate_random_char(choices):
    choice = random.choice(choices)
    
    if choice == 'upper':
        return random.choice(ascii_uppercase)
    
    if choice == 'lower':
        return random.choice(ascii_lowercase)
    
    if choice == 'symbol':
        return random.choice(punctuation)
    
    if choice == 'number':
        return random.choice(digits)

    raise ConfigurationError('bad configuration for password choices')
```

There are other ways to make sure it always returns a character, or you could just check for None, but I think you want to know if there's a configuration error, so an exception makes the most sense to me.